# TFileListBox Mask Issue

Tags: regex, delphi

The definition for [`TFileListBox.Mask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TFileListBox.Mask) is:

> Set **Mask** to a regular expression to limit the list box to files that
>   match the mask. The value of the mask is a file name that may include
>   wildcards. The asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard which matches any number of
>   arbitrary characters. The question mark (`?`) is a wildcard which
>   matches a single arbitrary character. The file mask `*.*` displays all
>   files, which is the default value.

The `*` wildcard works fine. However the `?` wildcard does not seem to work. I am trying to filter data files that have 14 digits.  Examples would be:

```
012345678909090.dat
012345678900123.dat
012345678901234.dat
012345678901235.dat
012345678901236.dat
```

If you were to set the mask to `*.23?.dat` the last four data files are returned. However, the second data file (`012345678900123.dat`) should not be returned if the `?` wildcard is doing its job.

By the way, this "problem" occurs in Raize Components TRzFileListBox and I imagine all others that derive from TFileListBox, too.

Any help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are u really using regular expressions OR filename wildcards ? dots and question marks are radically different in those. Are u sure that u really do use RegExp's ? Are you sure you understand what RegExp is and what question mark means in it ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegExp#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions

Comment: I'm unclear about the control that we are talking about. Is it `TFileListBox`, or is it `TRzFileListBox`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: AFAICT, it is TFileListBox, but components derived from it, like the Raize one, have the same problem.

Comment: Let as assume Embarcadero told wrong about RegExp and that is usual Windows/DOS filemask.  1: "*.23?.dat" Should not match anything at all, for there is now dot in the listed filenames. 2: in DOS 8.3 names (but not with Windows Long names) i experienced that "*xxx" mask matched anything, for * could go beyond 8 symbols and the rest was trimmed. However that should not happen with long names

Comment: The control passes the mask to 'FindFirstFile' exactly as is. See how the mask will work by browsing to the directory through a command prompt and then issue a dir (it outputs the 4 files you mention with `*23?.dat`). Then file your complaint to Microsoft. ;)

Comment: @Arioch - I guess wildcards can be considered as regular expressions, as they're a means to match a pattern to strings.

Comment: @Sertac perhaps he have "012345678900123 .dat"? Windows Explorer liked to do this to avoid name clashes in some version, don;t remember which and on what action

Comment: @Settac - they do not esigned this, they take it from granted from MS and it existed back before MS-DOS. So it is long established tradition./ And RegEx'es are the same. And they are different. Poor choice of words, misleading.

Comment: @Arioch - As far as I can see explorer is fine with it (W7). If I put `filename: *23?.dat` to the search box only three files are left. But the dir command does it as in the question. About the wording, I fully agree - misleading...

Comment: See above about 8.3 names. PErhaps command prompt is targeted with bug-compatibility dor the sake of legacy BAT-scripts

Comment: @Sertac: But `TFileListBox` doesn't use Explorer-compatible masks (they didn't exist). The control is a Win 3.1 compatible remnant of Delphi 1, and so follows the old DOS wildcard rules. There's no way that I can find to return the desired matches using those wildcards; it would appear that the poster needs to iterate through the results, checking with an actual regex (or `Masks.MatchesMask`) to see if it's really one of the files he wants. (Or, better yet, stop using Win3.1 controls and move up to modern `TOpenDialog` or  `TFileOpenDialog`.)

Comment: @Ken - It doesn't follow anything. It just passes the mask to `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` and populates the box with whatever they return. You're right about that there's no mask that would act as required.

Comment: @Sertac: FindFirstFile/etc. follow the old DOS rules as well, except that they support multiple `.` values and extensions longer than 3 chars. The wildcard operators and their functionality are the same, though - open a command window to see for yourself. :-) That's why I deleted my answer; there appears to be no mask that works for the desired results.

Comment: @Ken - Yes, I guess you could say that about FindFirstFile etc. follows the old rules. I know the command prompt acts the same, I suggested to do same in my first comment to the question.

Comment: Amazing answers.  Listen all.  This is a control that is still being used in Delphi 2010.  What I listed comes from the help file.  I was basically taking the control at its face value and applying that the instruction said concerning the mask property.  The "*" wildcard worked, however, the "?" wildcard does not work.  What is so complicated about that?  If the mask property on the control does not work, then it does not work.  It is a neat control for what I am using it for.

Comment: Basically it is fuel injector serial numbers with the 12th and 13th digits providing the fuel injector type.  I was trying to mask only those fuel injectors that passed the mask.